# How can you add working hours to date time

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a function where i can define working hours eg 9am - 5 pm and then add working hours to a datetime eg datetime 2021-08-05 16:30:00 add 3 working hours so the date time would be 2021-08-06 11:30:00.

I currently do this with working days see code below

This is to calculate SLA on a task eg task comes in at 2021-08-05 16:30:00 SLA is 3 working hours so it needs to be completed by 2021-08-06 11:30:00.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```
declare 
@ReturnDate     datetime,
@StartDate      datetime,
@CountDays      int,
@Country        varchar (255)  

set @StartDate  =  '2021-08-05 16:30:00.000'
set @CountDays  = 2
set @Country    = 'England and Wales'

;with cteWorkingDates as
    (
        select        DAT.Calendar_Date_Date,
                    ROW_NUMBER ()    over    (
                                            order by    DAT.Calendar_Date_Date
                                            ) as RowNo
        from        dwBoyce.archway.Calendar_Date        DAT    with (nolock)
        left join    dwBoyce.archway.GovUK_BankHolidays    BAH    with (nolock)    on    DAT.Calendar_Date_Date    = BAH.GovUK_BankHolidays_Date
                                                                            and    @Country                = BAH.GovUK_BankHolidays_Country
        where        DAT.Calendar_Date_Date > @StartDate
        and            DAT.Calendar_Date_WorkingDay = 1
        and            BAH.GovUK_BankHolidays_Date is null
    )
    select     cast(wd.Calendar_Date_Date as datetime) + DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, @StartDate), @StartDate)
    from    cteWorkingDates    WD
    where    WD.RowNo    = @CountDays
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this deals with SLAs that span over weekends

```
declare 
@date1 date = cast(@TicketTimestamp as date)
,@date2 date = cast(@TmpTimeStamp as date)
declare  @Count  int

Select @Count = count(*)
from archway.Calendar_Date d
where d.Calendar_Date_Date between @date1 and @date2
and Calendar_Date_DayName in ('Saturday','Sunday')

DECLARE @TmpTimeStamp1 DATETIME = case when @count = 2 then DATEADD(d,@count,@TmpTimeStamp)
else @TmpTimeStamp end
```

Comment: I guess the last `case` is not correct. This will only work, if a full weekend is between the two dates. What will happen, if your tmp date is a saturday? However, I guess you can simply stick with the `dateadd` without the `case` or at least change it to `case when @count > 0`.

Comment: @Tyron78 i think your right, your solution is much better! thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the following:

Evaluate, how many minutes of working time are remaining starting from the time the ticket has been created. Then calculate the number of minutes the SLA request may take (in your case 3 * 60 = 180 minutes). When the remaining working time is less than the SLA time in minutes, the answer time will be Ticket time + 1 day + (SLA minutes - remaining working time in minutes).

Following an example:

```
DECLARE @WorkingHoursStart TIME = '09:00:00.000';
DECLARE @WorkingHoursEnd TIME = '17:00:00.000';
DECLARE @WorkingHoursCount INT = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @WorkingHoursStart, @WorkingHoursEnd);

DECLARE @SLAHours INT = 32;
DECLARE @TicketTimestamp DATETIME = '2022-11-01 12:30:00';

DECLARE @TicketWorkingHoursStart DATETIME = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@TicketTimestamp)
                                                 ,MONTH(@TicketTimestamp)
                                                 ,DAY(@TicketTimestamp)
                                                 ,DATEPART(HOUR, @WorkingHoursStart)
                                                 ,DATEPART(MINUTE, @WorkingHoursStart)
                                                 ,0
                                                 ,0);

DECLARE @TicketWorkingHoursEnd DATETIME = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@TicketTimestamp)
                                                 ,MONTH(@TicketTimestamp)
                                                 ,DAY(@TicketTimestamp)
                                                 ,DATEPART(HOUR, @WorkingHoursEnd)
                                                 ,DATEPART(MINUTE, @WorkingHoursEnd)
                                                 ,0
                                                 ,0);

DECLARE @TicketWorkingTimestamp DATETIME = CASE
                                             WHEN @TicketTimestamp < @TicketWorkingHoursStart
                                               THEN @TicketWorkingHoursStart
                                             WHEN @TicketTimestamp > @TicketWorkingHoursEnd
                                               THEN DATEADD(d, 1, @TicketWorkingHoursStart)
                                              ELSE @TicketTimestamp
                                           END;

DECLARE @TmpTimeStamp DATETIME = DATEADD(d, @SLAHours/@WorkingHoursCount, @TicketWorkingTimestamp);

DECLARE @TmpSLAHours INT = @SLAHours - ((@SLAHours/@WorkingHoursCount)*@WorkingHoursCount);
DECLARE @TmpSLAMinutes INT = @TmpSLAHours * 60;

DECLARE @AnswerTimestamp DATETIME = CASE
         WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(@TmpTimeStamp AS TIME), @WorkingHoursEnd) < @TmpSLAMinutes
           THEN DATEADD(MINUTE
                       ,@TmpSLAMinutes - DATEDIFF(MINUTE
                                                 ,CAST(@TmpTimeStamp AS TIME)
                                                 ,@WorkingHoursEnd)
                       ,DATEADD(DAY
                               ,CASE WHEN @TmpSLAHours/@WorkingHoursCount = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                               ,DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@TmpTimeStamp)
                                                 ,MONTH(@TmpTimeStamp)
                                                 ,DAY(@TmpTimeStamp)
                                                 ,DATEPART(HOUR, @WorkingHoursStart)
                                                 ,DATEPART(MINUTE, @WorkingHoursStart)
                                                 ,DATEPART(SECOND, @TmpTimeStamp)
                                                 ,0)
                                )
                        )
           ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, @TmpSLAMinutes, @TmpTimeStamp)
       END

DECLARE @WeekEndDaySkip INT = ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TicketTimestamp)+DATEDIFF(d, @TicketTimestamp, @AnswerTimestamp))/7)*2

SELECT @TicketTimestamp AS TicketTime
     , @AnswerTimestamp AS AnswerTimestamp
     , DATEADD(d, @WeekEndDaySkip, @AnswerTimestamp) AS AnswerTimestampWOWeekend
```

Comment: Hi @tyron78, thanks for the above however if you pass in TicketTimestamp after 17:00 eg '2021-08-05 17:30:00' the AnswerTimestamp is 2021-08-06 12:30:00.000 and not 2021-08-06 12:00:00.000 any ideas how i can resolve, similarly if you pass in 08:30:00 eg 30 mins before start time the Answer time is 12:30:00 and not 12:00

Comment: @LewisWilliams yes you are right... I modified the answer

Comment: Hi @tyron78, long time response, wondered if you were able to help, the above works correct for adding hours to a date time within working hours, however for example if the ticket time is '2022-11-04 12:30:00.000' and the SLA hours is 32 hours it caluclates it as  '2022-11-08 12:30:00.000', which is including sat and sunday which are not working hours for us, any ideas how i can change to not include weekends?

Comment: @LewisWilliams Hello. I modified my answer accordingly - please check. The idea is to add the days of all included weegends to the answer-time, so the weekends are skipped / not considered as working hours.